# Find empty lines in a .txt using .bat/cmd

Tags: cmd, find, line

I have a txt file that has some lines that are empty
How can i get the numbers of lines that are empty in a .txt file?

I would like to do this using either .bat or cmd line

Answer (score 1):

```
findstr /n /v "." file.txt
```

`/n` gives the lines with leading linenumbers (or just linenumbers for empty lines)

`/v` only list lines that DOESN'T contain ...

`"."` ... any char in

```
file.txt
```

Comment: and how can i return those lines (print them) in another .txt ?

Comment: nvm i found it using >> filename . The problem is that it stops for some reason and prints only for 3 lines.

Comment: what is the "last written line" and the "first missing line"?

Comment: It may be that the last line in your text file doesn't end with a CRLF as findstr hangs sometimes when that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

This will count blank lines containing no text, and no spaces etc.

```
findstr /n "^$" "file.txt" |find /c /v ""
```